# Chain Rule For Limits

Tags: limits

Given a function $f:\mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is continuous and has a limit at $p=\infty$, $\lim_{x\rightarrow p}f(x,y)=b(y)$ and a function $g:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is continuous and has a limit at $p$, $\lim_{x\rightarrow p}g(x)=c$, is the following statement true?
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow p}f(x,g(x))=\lim_{x\rightarrow p}f(x,c)=b(c)$$

Comment: Yes: it is true. It is a direct consequence of continuity of $f,g$.

Comment: If the functions are continuous and defined everywhere then we do not need to talk about limits - it is just the functional value $f(p,g(p))$.

Comment: In general, there is no such rule for the limits. It is not recommended to take partial (sequential) limits with respect to some $x$ while keeping other as $x$, it may easily give a wrong result, for example, $\lim_{x\to 0}x\cdot\frac{1}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0}0\cdot\frac{1}{x}=0$ is wrong as you may see.

Comment: Yes, I know that in general the chain rule does not apply to limits. I want to be sure that I am correctly applying it in this specific case I outline. In the example you give, $lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac 1 x$ does not exist so it doesn't fit my example.

Comment: @A.G. Note that the question says that $p = \infty$.

Comment: @Ezueneok oh, really? I've missed it. Then it is not true.

Comment: Is there a notion of "continuous at infinity" that will make this statement true? Or any additional restrictions on $f$ and $g$?

Comment: I guess your $b(y)$ must be continuous too. What you basically do is the switching of limit order: you need to know when $\lim_{x\to p}\lim_{y\to c}f(x,y)=\lim_{y\to c}\lim_{x\to p}f(x,y)$. As far as I remember, one of the limits should be uniform, it is sufficient, but check it.

Comment: Check out [here](http://www.math.unm.edu/~loring/links/analysis_f10/exchange.pdf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $p=\infty$ it is not true. A counterexample:
$$
f(x,y)=\frac{1}{x^2|y|+1}\to b(y)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
0, & \text{if } y\ne 0,\\
1, & \text{if } y= 0.
\end{array}
\right.
$$
$$
g(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+1}\to c=0.
$$
So we have $f(x,c)=f(x,0)=1$, but
$$
f(x,g(x))=\frac{1}{\frac{x^2}{x^2+1}+1}\to \frac12.
$$

Comment: Thanks! So I need to assume that $b(y)$ is continuous to make the statement true.